# Intersection types with arrays and array methods cannot find all fields

Tags: arrays, typescript, union-types

I've got two types that are both an array of objects, with their fields, in an intersection type in Typescript.

If I take an element from the array I can access the second field, but if I use an array method (forEach, map, filter etc) the compiler doesn't work.

Is there a particular reason why in a case work but fails in the other?

Here a sample code:

```js
var obj: {
  foo?: string;
}[] & {
  bar?: boolean;
}[] = [{foo: "a", bar: true}];

obj.forEach((q) => q.bar); // bar does not exist
obj.map((q) => q.bar) // bar does not exist
obj[0].bar; // OK
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9gRgVgLggbwFAQgMylA-EgZwBcwBLAOwHMBuVAXwG0BdCAMhXQhnHy5wBsApiHK1GLALwQGybFCQAiEAoA0XcEhIBXQXSa1UsOADpsYAKIgAxgAsAFHYCOASggSAfBEfHuYZ9QgAekD1SAATKEECCHIoIghBAA9SYkN4YwBbEAAHBxc3T29fV2DQiAiomLiE5NSjBgAGJh9wANKAeQBpVCA)

Comment: that's an intersection

Comment: I wrote it right in the title, wrong in the text. Fixed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per Ryan Cavanaugh](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11961) (active member fo the TypeScript team), it is a bad idea to have an intersection of 2 array types.

> This happens because we just merge the signatures of forEach in order,
> whereas element access produces the recursively merged property type.
> You could specify a type annotation on item, or write type foo3 = foo2
> & foo1 (!).
>
> But in general it's really unclear how type TU = T[] & U[] should be
> interpreted -- is it a heterogeneous array, the same as Array<T | U> ?
> Or the same as Array<T & U> ? An axiom is that for any operation
> x.y(z), that should still be legal for x if x becomes an intersection
> type containing the original constituent, but that wouldn't be true if
> we interpreted the array to be Array<T & U> (since z would have to be
> the intersected element type as well).
>
> So overall... probably a bad idea to have the type T[] & U[] floating
> around.

What you probably should have is `Array<{ foo?: string;} & {bar?: boolean}>`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9gRgVgLggQTGEBPAPAbwgMyigH4kBnAFzAEsA7AcwG4IBfCAMgjxnFIhiIAbAKYharAHwQAvBADaeQlCQAiECoA0-cEioBXYawC6jAFCnYcAHSEwAURABjABYAKVwEcAlDKkerPGBezAD0IdqQACZQwmQQtFAUEMIAHtSUFvBWALYgAA7u3r4Q-oE%20YREQ0bHxiclpGZZyAAxGAeCh4QDyANKmQA)

Answer (score 1):

It would be more obvious to understand if you write down array types:

```js
type ItemFoo = {
  foo?: string;
};
type ArrFoo = ItemFoo[];

type ItemBar = {
  bar?: boolean;
};
type ArrBar = ItemBar[];


const obj: ArrFoo & ArrBar = [{foo: "a", bar: true}];
```

So you can notice `ArrFoo` has `forEach(cb: (x: ItemFoo, i?) => void)` method, and `ArrBar` has `forEach(cb: (x:ItemBar, i?) => void)` method. And when the type merge happens, only one signature is taken.

If you have access just to the `ArrFoo` and `ArrBar` types, make the intersection of item types

```js
const obj: (ArrFoo[0] & ArrBar[0])[] = [{foo: "a", bar: true}];
```

Or with the Helper Type.

```js
type ArrIntersection<T1 extends Array<any>, T2 extends Array<any>> = (T1[0] & T2[0])[];

const obj: ArrIntersection<ArrFoo, ArrBar> = [{foo: "a", bar: true}];
```